# Newsletter sending from 1and1 to 2k different emails in PHP

Tags: php, email, cron, newsletter

I have been working on this subject for a long time now and to be honest I am in need of some help if you guys have some time to answer to my problem ;)

I have a few k of emails in my database (around 2k and coming up...) and I would like to send two newsletters a week ... what would be the best way to achieve that ?

So far here is what I am doing :
- a script php (with meta tag refresh set to 600) which sends every 10 minutes an email to 50 people (using basic mail() function). It runs for 6 hours to get to the 2k emails. I am using the less expensive shared server at 1and1 (2EUR a month :D).

1- Is this way to proceed a good way ? I heard when you put people in BCC you go to SPAM directly ... Also many people do not even receive the emails ... no idea why. So far it is not really conclusive.

2- Do you think it would worth taking the dedicated server and send 1 email to each people thats to say 2k different emails ? Or is it a bad move ?

3- How do people proceed when sending newsletters ? I'm sure I look ridiculous with 2k emails and though I have difficulties in making my way through this ;)

Any help welcome.

Cheers.
G/

Comment: That seems a little excessive for a small server, could you not use a service like [mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) instead?

Comment: Thought about that but I like to manage my own list and my own URLs so I finally passed on it. Don't want my users to get redirected to mailChimp when unsubscribing ...  Plus there is a logo on the free version :D

Comment: Fair enough, I've never used their services, but heard only good things. 2000 emails, personally seems like a lot to be sending through a small server using a provider such as 1and1 and I think they would have something to say about it after a while. You might get away with setting up a cron job to send say 50 emails every x minutes? It'd be a much better setup than a meta-refresh for sure! The main problem you will have though is dealing with your emails going straight to spam though :(

Comment: What would be the difference between a cron job and a meta refresh ? And is there anything I can do to avoid spam ? How does mailchimp do ?

Comment: Well a meta-refresh usually involves requiring a web page to be open for the length of time it takes to send all the emails, many many hours. A cron job is something you set and forget and it *should* continue running as long as the server is online. Unfortunately many mail services report emails sent with `mail()` as spam, I think there are ways to avoid this using certain headers in the email, but I'm not 100% sure, have a search and see if you can find anything related to this issue. I think mailchimp use many different SMTP servers, and are probably on a lot of services white lists.

Answer (score 0):

1. maximize time between connections to same mail servers
2. maximize number of servers you use
3. send to one person at a time
4. include images, text and html version, unsubscribe link
5. Check what mail servers respond (like IP blocking notice with link to unblock)

And yes, use cron